# How to delete (not deactivate) a user?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I created a team over the weekend. However, because I was logged in to this account ([Turnip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746736/turnip)) at the time, this account became the admin user for the team.

I have since added an additional admin user and deactivated this account.

I do not want this account to display in the 'Inactive' tab or to be associated with the team in any way. How can I remove a user from the team entirely?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once an account has been active in a team, it is no longer possible to remove an account via the team's admin interface - you can only deactivate them. Deactivated users do not count towards billing, nor do they have any access to your team.

Please send an email to teams-support@stackoverflow with your request and we can manually remove them.

Comment: These "deactivated" do not count towards the user count regarding billing, right?

Comment: Isn't this very inefficient? If every team needs to contact the company every time they want to remove someone from the team, doesn't that stack up to a lot of requests and a long waiting time?

Comment: @Zoe I would imagine that if deactivated users does not count towards billing, actually "removing" them would not be a primary concern for most teams.

Comment: @yivi If deactivated users count towards billing, a 2 month backlog to get a user removed is pretty bad too.

Comment: But @Zoe if they don't count, the concern is mostly moot. That's my point. Can you confirm if they do or if they don't? Could not find that info myself yet.

Comment: @yivi I have no idea - I don't have a team either, so I can't test. I get how quickly the user gets removed isn't necessarily important to most teams, but unless they have dedicated support staff for team requests, those requests will fill up a backlog containing all kinds of requests that require staff intervention

Comment: Deactivated users do not count towards billing. Once deactivated, they have nothing to do with the team. They're listed as deactivated for administrative reason.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Juice. It's useful to keep be able to keep user "entities" around for historical purposes, without them being part of the team any longer.

Comment: Thanks @Juice. Presumably users can't be deleted because they could be linked to posts/comments/votes etc? Could we have the ability to delete users who haven't interacted with the system in any of these ways?

Comment: @Juice is this still the case? Or do deactivated users now count towards billing, since we can delete users now?